# img tag not displaying images when using with ejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm working with express, ejs and mongoose . i have list of products in mongoDB and i want to display images of products which is store in my local storage. i used express.static method to access images. my images named like this SAMSUNG Galaxy M33 5G (Emarld Brown, 128 GB) (6 GB RAM) , i saved their name in an array ( like object ) called category. my code is following

```
    <% for( list of category){ %> 
        <ul>
            <img src="/<%=list.name%>.jpeg" alt="<%=list.name %>">
            <li><%= list.name %> </li>
        </ul>
     <% } %>
```

in this case no image is displayed but when i removed brackets () from the name of image ( like this SAMSUNG Galaxy M33 5G Emarld Brown, 128 GB 6 GB RAM ) it start working like wonder but i have so many images and i cant change name of all images please help me to solve this problem

Comment: try encoding the filename https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: i tried encodeURI() but its not working. i think ejs may be creating this problem

Comment: Can you post the `<img>` element as it appears in the HTML source received by the browser?

Comment: yes. i do, i did research and find out the problem is uri encoding, now i need to find solution. i try encodeURI() but it didn't work